# How to parse out a piece of data after printing from awk

Tags: awk

say i have a line of text in a file as follows:

```
-config1=/path/to/config1.cfg -config2=/path/toconfig2.cfg -input=/path/to/file.txt -output=/path/to/file.out
```

How can i have awk parse out only `-input=/path/to/file.txt`

Right now i'm doing:

```
echo $data | awk -F"-input=" '{print $2}'
```

and it returns to me the entire line above.

Is there a way to do this without using the cut command? Not that i CAN'T use it but, i'm trying to avoid a lot of fork/execs.

Edit: I rushed typing this question. What i really wanted to get my hands on was the name of the input file. In my example that would be `file.txt`. I was using `-input=` as a delimeter to awk because at first i thought i wanted `/path/to/file.txt`. This returned to me `/path/to/file.txt -output=/path/to/file.out`. Which i did not want.

Later I realized that i really just wanted/needed the name of the input file.

Sorry about that!

Comment: `echo "$data" | awk '{ print $3 }'` ?? unless your file names/paths have spaces.

Comment: awk is working as designed. $2 when you set -F"-input=" will strip out the FS value, and print everything to the right of the FS as $2. The other suggestions are on better ways to think about this problem. Good luck.

Comment: You've changed the requirements in comments on answers, where you say that you not only do _not_ want the `-input=` prefix, but in fact only want the _filename component_ of the path. Please update your question and also state how the requirements _changed later_, so as not to invalidate older answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the OP changed the requirements through comments not yet reflected in the question:

- the `-input=` prefix should NOT be captured
- indeed, only the *filename* component of the path should be captured (only `file.txt` in the sample data)

If you have **GNU** `grep` with support for the `-P` option (to enable PCRE (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions) support), you can get away with a **single command**:

```
echo "$data" | grep -Po '(^| )-input=([^ /]*/)*\K[^ ]*'
```

Note: assumes that the  file paths do not contain embedded spaces.

- `-P` activates PCRE support
- `-o` only outputs what the regex matches
- `\K` inside the regex simply drops everything matched so far, resulting only in the filename component getting output.
  More specifically, the components of the regex are:

  - `(^| )-input=` matches the literal `-input=` either at the very beginning of the input or if preceded by at least 1 space.
  - `([^ /]*/)*` matches any number of path components (strings of any length not containing a space or `/`, terminated by `/`)
  - `\K`, as mentioned, drops everything matched so far.
  - `[^ ]*` then constitutes the match that is returned (effectively, the filename component of the path): any sequence of non-space characters up to the next space or end of the string.

Comment: This is pretty sexy. If you have time do you think you could break the regular expression down?

Comment: Thanks @mklement0. I was getting confused with the meaning of the `^` at the beginning and the `^` a little later in the expression. The first one means match the beginning and the second one means negation. Correct?

Comment: @rage: Correct: _inside a character set_ (`[...]`), `^` means _negation_; otherwise, it is an _anchor_ that matches the _beginning of a line_ / _overall input_ (depending on regex dialect and options specified; with `grep`, it's the beginning of the _line_.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a special reason you are setting the separator to `-input=`? If you don't have whitespace in your file/dirnames, you can just use

```
echo $data | awk -F\  '{print $3}'
```

Alternatively

```
echo $data | grep -o "\-input=[^\ ]*"
```

In response to your comment: To get only `file.txt`, you can chain another `| grep -o "[^/]*$"` behind the first or second command.

Comment: i was using `-input=` because i didn't want that in my output... now that i think about it i really don't wany any of the output other than `file.txt`

Comment: @rage you could chain another | grep -o "[^/]*$" behind the first or second command. Probably not the most efficient solution ever, though. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $data | awk '{print $3}' | awk -F\/ '{print $NF}'  # if no spaces in directory or filenames, as in the example, this prints the 'file.txt' only.
```

Comment: +1 for a pragmatic solution (invoking `awk` again to extract the path's filename component).

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the whole line with your example, i get:

```
$ echo $data | awk -F"-input=" '{print $2}'
/path/to/file.txt -output=/path/to/file.out
```

You can awk/grep/awk if you want.  But if you have access to sed, this is no more costly than your call to awk:

```
echo $data | sed -n 's/^.*-input=\(.*\) \(.*\)$/\1/p'
```

That's assuming you really want the value, otherwise just change the grouping to:

```
echo $data | sed -n 's/^.*\(-input=.*\) \(.*\)$/\1/p'
```

Comment: +1 for recommending `sed` for this task; you don't need the 2nd capture group, though.

Comment: Fair point.  The second group is to force that space to match, otherwise you might capture `-input=/some/file -output=/other/file -optfoo=X`.  It could be accomplished by other means, but without more robust sample data, this is simple enough.  I also imagine the possibility that more than one extraction per line might be needed.

Comment: I see. However, the 2nd capture group doesn't actually prevent greedy matching of the space; what you need is: `sed -n 's/^.*-input=\([^ ]*\) .*$/\1/p'` (you could still add a 2nd capture group if you wanted, but it's using `[^ ]*` instead of `.*` that makes the difference).

Comment: You are correct again, but the example is sufficient for the single line of sample input provided.  The filename *might* also contain whitespace and other perturbing factors.  Basically, greater specification or minor adaptation are required.