# Remove noisy pieces of html-extracted text in a shell script using regex

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I loop through urls in my script and get a piece from html code extracted with Apache Tika for further processing.

```
    while read p; do   curl -s $p | curl -X PUT -T - http://10.0.2.208:9998/tika | head -1000; done < ~/file_with_urls.txt
```

Where urls are for example:

```
    http://dailycurrant.com/2014/01/02/marijuana-overdoses-kill-37-in-colorado-on-first-day-of-legalization/
    http://www.sott.net/article/271748-Father-sentenced-to-6-months-in-jail-for-paying-too-much-child-support
    http://www.sunnyskyz.com/blog/79/The-27-Naughtiest-Cats-In-The-World-And-I-Can-t-Stop-Laughing
```

In a shell script I would like to do the following: skip or delete everything that comes in a form [image: *some text*], [bookmark: *some text*].

```
   [image: USA][image: Map][image: Print][image: Hall and Son][image: Google+][image: FB Share][image: ][image: Email][image: Print this article][image: Discuss on Cassiopaea Forum][image: Pin it][bookmark: comment96580][bookmark: reply18433][bookmark: reply18457][bookmark: reply18484][bookmark: reply18487][bookmark: comment96583][image: Hugh Mann][bookmark: comment96595][image: Animanarchy][bookmark: reply18488][bookmark: comment96610][bookmark: reply18485][bookmark: comment96632][image: Close][image: Loading...] Plain text starts here
```

Out of the above I would only need "Plain text starts here".

Can I accomplish with regex using GNU grep with support for the -P option (to enable PCRE (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions) support), something like recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044418/how-to-parse-out-a-piece-of-data-after-printing-from-awk):

```
    while read p; do   curl -s $p | curl -X PUT -T - http://10.0.2.208:9998/tika | head -1000 | grep -Po '_regex that will do the trick_'; done < ~/file_with_urls.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
str='[image: USA][image: Map][image: Print][image: Hall and Son][image: Google+][image: FB Share][image: ][image: Email][image: Print this article][image: Discuss on Cassiopaea Forum][image: Pin it][bookmark: comment96580][bookmark: reply18433][bookmark: reply18457][bookmark: reply18484][bookmark: reply18487][bookmark: comment96583][image: Hugh Mann][bookmark: comment96595][image: Animanarchy][bookmark: reply18488][bookmark: comment96610][bookmark: reply18485][bookmark: comment96632][image: Close][image: Loading...] Plain text starts here'
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\\[[^]]*\\] *"} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i) print $i}' <<< "$str"
Plain text starts here
```

Here `$str` represents your long string given above.

Comment: My understanding that separator now is everything that comes surrounded with []. But I don't know how many of them I have in the text. This seem to work while read p; do   curl -s $p | curl -X PUT -T - http://10.0.2.208:9998/tika | head -300 | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\\[.*\\] *"} {print $1,$2,$3,$4}'; done < ~/file_with_urls.txt. How can I print all. Processing speed matters here a lot too.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why this modification does not work: while read p; do   tk = $(curl -s $p | curl -X PUT -T - http://10.0.2.208:9998/tika | head -1000 | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\\[[^]]*\\] *"} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i) print $i}');  printf "%s\t%s" "$p" "$tk"; done < ~/file_with_urls.txt

Comment: It is difficult for me to guess since I don't know output of `curl -s $p | curl -X PUT -T - 10.0.2.208:9998/tika | head -1000` command and also unaware of your expected output.

Comment: curl -s "http://dailycurrant.com/2014/01/02/marijuana-overdoses-kill-37-in-colorado-on-first-day-of-legalization/" | curl -X PUT -T - http://10.0.2.208:9998/tika | head -1000

Comment: This gives the text I am processing. What doesn't work now if I want to print the original url and then processed text associated with it. Each line in file with urls is $p. All the text output I output=$(<text>); echo $output

Comment: If you can provide me output of `curl -s "http://dailycurrant.com/2014/01/02/…; | curl -X PUT -T - http://10.0.2.208:9998/tika | head -1000` in your question then I can examine this awk command